# Prevent Deletion of Printers Enabled, but does not work

Tags: group-policy, printer

I've got a GPO that is linked to the OU with all our user accounts.

I've got some printers in the GPO.
GPO > User Config > Preferences > Control Panel > Printers > (Printers)

I've enabled 'prevent deletion of printers.'
GPO > User Config > Policies > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Printers > Prevent Deletion of Printers (Enabled)

I go to a user's computer. I update the policy with GPUPDATE /FORCE.
Printer shows up as expected. Right click printer > Remove Device. Success, printer removed.

What gives?

Thank you,

Chris

EDIT: GPRESULT from a user:

C:\Users\Marie>gpresult /v

Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-2001

Created On 5/11/2018 at 1:50:13 PM

### RSOP data for SMC\mmckenzie on MARIE-PC : Logging Mode

OS Configuration:            Member Workstation
OS Version:                  6.1.7601
Site Name:                   N/A
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\Marie
Connected over a slow link?: No

### USER SETTINGS

```
CN=Marie Hodges,OU=Accounts,OU=SMC,DC=i,DC=*REDACTED*,DC=com
Last time Group Policy was applied: 5/11/2018 at 1:35:16 PM
Group Policy was applied from:      SVR01.i.*REDACTED*.com
Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
Domain Name:                        SMC
Domain Type:                        Windows 2000

Applied Group Policy Objects
-----------------------------
    Mapped Drives
    Mapped Printers
    Default Domain Policy

The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Local Group Policy
        Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

The user is a part of the following security groups
---------------------------------------------------
    Domain Users
    Everyone
    BUILTIN\Administrators
    BUILTIN\Users
    NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
    CONSOLE LOGON
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
    This Organization
    LOCAL
    PrintGroup-Administration
    Authentication authority asserted identity
    High Mandatory Level

The user has the following security privileges
----------------------------------------------


Resultant Set Of Policies for User
-----------------------------------

    Software Installations
    ----------------------
        N/A

    Logon Scripts
    -------------
        N/A

    Logoff Scripts
    --------------
        N/A

    Public Key Policies
    -------------------
        N/A

    Administrative Templates
    ------------------------
        GPO: Mapped Printers
            KeyName:     Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDeletePrinter
            Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

    Folder Redirection
    ------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer Browser User Interface
    ----------------------------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer Connection
    ----------------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer URLs
    ----------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer Security
    --------------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer Programs
    --------------------------
        N/A
```

C:\Users\Marie>

Comment: I can't find any scenario in my testing where this doesn't work correctly. Are you filtering the GPO?

Comment: Leave it to me to mess something up. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by filtering. The security filtering for this GPO only has Authenticated Users in the list.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. Authenticated Users is the default, and as such, should work. Run gpresult on the machine while the user is logged on and post the resultant report in your question.

Comment: It should work from the looks of it, yeah?

Comment: Yes, it should. I can't see any reason why it wouldn't be working. In my lab tests it works perfectly.

Comment: If I deploy the printer with a GPO in Print Management (the way you said I shouldn't do it) the policy will apply and I wont be able to delete printers.
If I Item-Level Target like you suggested, the policy wont apply.
What do you think about that?

Comment: I tried it both ways in my lab and was prevented from deleting printers. Let me give it another go later and see what I can come up with.